# PDF plotting concern

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I tried the following manual approach:

```
dict = {'id': ['a','b','c','d'], 'testers_time': [10, 30, 15, None], 'stage_1_to_2_time': [30, None, 30, None], 'activated_time' : [40, None, 45, None],'stage_2_to_3_time' : [30, None, None, None],'engaged_time' : [70, None, None, None]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['id', 'testers_time', 'stage_1_to_2_time', 'activated_time', 'stage_2_to_3_time', 'engaged_time'])

df= df.dropna(subset=['testers_time']).sort_values('testers_time')

prob = df['testers_time'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print(prob)
#0.333333,  0.333333,  0.333333
plt.plot(df['testers_time'], prob, marker='.', linestyle='-') 

plt.show()
```

And I tried the following approach I found on stackoverflow:

```
dict = {'id': ['a','b','c','d'], 'testers_time': [10, 30, 15, None], 'stage_1_to_2_time': [30, None, 30, None], 'activated_time' : [40, None, 45, None],'stage_2_to_3_time' : [30, None, None, None],'engaged_time' : [70, None, None, None]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['id', 'testers_time', 'stage_1_to_2_time', 'activated_time', 'stage_2_to_3_time', 'engaged_time'])

df= df.dropna(subset=['testers_time']).sort_values('testers_time')

fit = stats.norm.pdf(df['testers_time'], np.mean(df['testers_time']), np.std(df['testers_time']))  
print(fit)
#0.02902547,  0.04346777,  0.01829513]
plt.plot(df['testers_time'], fit, marker='.', linestyle='-')
plt.hist(df['testers_time'], normed='true')      

plt.show()
```

As you can see I get completely different values- the probabilities are correct for #1, but for #2 they aren't (nor do they add up to 100%), and the y axis (%) of the histogram is based on 6 bins, not 3.

Can you explain how I can get the right probability for #2?

Comment: The first approach gives you a probability. The second gives you a probability **density** - hence the name probability **density** function (pdf). Hence both are correct, they just show something different.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest so is the first one a probability distribution function? or does it have some other name?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest also if second one is a PDF then why doesnt it start at 0?

Comment: It would be a probability **mass** function.

Comment: You choose the values at which this function is evaluated yourself. If you include any extremal value it will be 0 at that point.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Much appreciate the explanation! Can you clarify how I can change it to start from 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach gives you a probability **mass** function. The second gives you a probability **density** - hence the name probability density function (pdf). Hence both are correct, they just show something different.

If you evaluate the pdf over a larger range (e.g. 10 times the standard deviation), it will look much like an expected gaussian curve.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict = {'id': ['a','b','c','d'], 'testers_time': [10, 30, 15, None], 'stage_1_to_2_time': [30, None, 30, None], 'activated_time' : [40, None, 45, None],'stage_2_to_3_time' : [30, None, None, None],'engaged_time' : [70, None, None, None]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['id', 'testers_time', 'stage_1_to_2_time', 'activated_time', 'stage_2_to_3_time', 'engaged_time'])

df= df.dropna(subset=['testers_time']).sort_values('testers_time')

mean = np.mean(df['testers_time'])
std = np.std(df['testers_time'])
x = np.linspace(mean - 5*std, mean + 5*std)

fit = stats.norm.pdf(x, mean, std)  
print(fit)

plt.plot(x, fit, marker='.', linestyle='-')
plt.hist(df['testers_time'], normed='true')      

plt.show()
```

[image]